# Putty-like "Session Log" for gnome-terminal?

Tags: logs, gnome-terminal

Is there a log feature for `gnome-terminal` like the "session log" in Putty? I want to log whatever I have typed in the gnome-terminal.

I don't want to use `pterm` under Linux, I just want a `gnome-terminal`.

See an [example log here](http://www.planetmy.com/blog/how-to-capture-putty-session-log/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `script` (the command, not 'a script'!) to log shell sessions.

Here's [some info at about.com](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_script.htm).